# Ajuda ao logar em sistema de login, sumir os 2 form's

Tags: php, html, mysql

Bom estou querendo deixar um sistema de login que após seja validado o login quando for para a pagina do form do login aparecer que ele está logado e não o form de login:
ex:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

apoós logar na mesma pagina sumisse esse form:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

codigo php:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    require 'init.php';
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>x1</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css.css">
</head>

<body>

<header>
<div id="logobuscar">
<div id="wrapperlogo">
<div id="logo"><img src="images/logosecure.png" alt="SecureStore" height="120" width="120"></div>
<div id="buscar">   <?php
                $sessao = $_SESSION['pedido'];
                $consulta = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM carrinho_temporario WHERE temporario_sessao =:ses");
                $consulta -> bindValue(':ses', $sessao);
                $consulta -> execute();
                $linhas = $consulta -> rowCount();
                ?>
                <p class="text-right "><a href="carrinho.php" class="color-white bgcolor-red font-text-light font-weight-heavy car_show">Carrinho(<?= $linhas ?>)</a></p><br>
                <h1 class="color-white text-center font-text-hard-two font-weight-heavy link-bgcolor-black">PRODUTOS</h1>
</form></div>
</div>
</div>  
<div id="mainmenu">
<div id="wrappermenu">
<nav class="menu">
<ul class="x1">
<a href="#"><li>Inicio</li></a>
<a href="#"><li>Sobre</li></a>
<a href="#"><li>Loja</li></a>
<a href="#"><li>Contato</li></a>
</ul>

<ul class="x2">
<a href="#"><li>Cadastrar</li></a>
<a href="logar.php"><li>Login</li></a>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
</div>
</header>
    <div id="wrapperleft"></div>

    <div id="wrapper">
           <form action="login.php" method="post">
            <label for="email">Email: </label>
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email">

            <br><br>

            <label for="password">Senha: </label>
            <br>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password">

            <br><br>

            <input type="submit" value="Entrar">
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="wrapperright"></div>

<footer>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

codigo da validação:

```
<?php

// inclui o arquivo de inicialização
require 'init.php';


// resgata variáveis do formulário
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
$password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : '';

if (empty($email) || empty($password))
{
    echo "Informe login e senha";
    exit;
}

// cria o hash da senha
$passwordHash = make_hash($password);

$PDO = db_connect();

$sql = "SELECT id, nome, adm FROM users WHERE login = :email AND password = :password";
$stmt = $PDO->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
$stmt->bindParam(':password', $passwordHash);

$stmt->execute();

$users = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (count($users) <= 0)
{
    echo "login ou senha incorretos";
    exit;
}

// pega o primeiro usuário
$user = $users[0];

session_start();
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['id'];
$_SESSION['user_name'] = $user['name'];
$dados=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
if($dados['adm'] == '1') header("Location: administrativo.php");
header('Location: logar.php');
```

Comment: Você sabe me dizer quando ele está logado?

Comment: Eu botei para quando logar ele votar para mesma pagina. logar.php'

Comment: Só que quando eu aperto no link logar ou no diretorio /logar.php ainda aparece o form.

Comment: Eu queria fazer, quando o usuario logar mesmo ele votando para pagina logar.php sumir o form e aparecer outra coisa ( um painel )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta verificar se não está logado para apresentar o formulário

```
<?php
if ($_SESSION['logged_in'] != true){
?>


       <form action="login.php" method="post">
        <label for="email">Email: </label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email">

        <br><br>

        <label for="password">Senha: </label>
        <br>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password">

        <br><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Entrar">
    </form>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

**outra forma**

crie uma session na login `$_SESSION['esconder'] = "display: none;";`

**e na tag form da logar**

```
<form action="login.php" method="post" style="<?php echo $_SESSION['esconder'] ?>">
```

> você deve fazer isso se o login for válidado

adendo:

```
<?php
if ($_SESSION['logged_in'] != true){

    echo '<a href="logar.php"><li>Login</li></a>';

}else{

    echo $_SESSION['user_name'];
}
?>
```

Comment: show @leo, mt obrigado .

Comment: @GabrielCosta, quanto ao `Undefined index logged_in` , o que ocorre é o seguinte: se vc desloga essa session não existe, portanto no arquivo logar ao fazer a pergunta `if ($_SESSION['logged_in'] != true){` o PHP não vai saber avaliar porque se a session não existe como vai poder comparar algo que não existe com algum valor? ai ele exibe esse erro. Para evitar esse aviso você pode usar `if (!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {` que significa  `se a session não existir`.  Isset verifica se foi inicializada, ou seja, se existe, e o ponto de interjeição a negação.